# iOS, how to convert NSString to MBCS

Tags: ios, string

I am working on an iOS project, need convert a NSString to a MBCS(multi-byte string in VC++).

Can anybody help me?

Thank you.

Comment: How are accessing this MBCS?

Comment: Just put in memory and send out via network.

Comment: So are you reading information from a packet?